# How to add WYSIWYG Editor to Dynamic fields in System Configuration in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, system-configuration

I want to add WYSIWYG Editor in Dynamic fields in System Configuration .
[image]

Comment: Share the code of the module here so that we can suggest the edit or you can refer to this link https://webkul.com/blog/add-wysiwyg-editor-in-magento2-configuration-section/

Answer (score 2):

Step1# open your module system.xml from

```
app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="yoursectionid" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Custom Label</label>
            <tab>tabname</tab>
            <resource>NameSpace_ModuleNmae::config_modulename</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Settings</label>
                <!-- WYSIWYG editor field code start-->
                <field id="editor_textarea" translate="label comment" sortOrder="1" type="editor" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" >
                    <label>WYSIWYG Editor</label>
                    <frontend_model>NameSpace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Editor</frontend_model>
                </field>
                <!-- WYSIWYG editor field code end-->
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

step #2 :
 Now we create Editor class in file `Editor.php` at `app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/Bloc/Adminhtml/System/Config` folder where we create WYSIWYG editor element

```
<?php
namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config as WysiwygConfig;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Editor extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    /**
     * @var  Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @param Context       $context
     * @param WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig
     * @param array         $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        // set wysiwyg for element
        $element->setWysiwyg(true);
        // set configuration values 
        $element->setConfig($this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig($element));
        return parent::_getElementHtml($element);
    }
}
```

Thanks :-)

**Please Reference This Coding this will help you :-)**

Comment: I have just tried your code and the editor appears +1 but the insert image and variable don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: MagentoCmsModelTemplateFilterProvider $filterProvider                       
  $content = ‘{{media url=”wysiwyg/some_image.jpg”}}’;                                                                                                                                                                               
$contentGenerating = $this->_filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($content);                                                                                              
echo $contentGenerating; //Generate HTML

Comment: @Divyesh could you update your code with answer provided in  the comment